# Not able to fetch values from Maptype Column in Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the below values in data frame Usage_Service_Union.

> (Usage_Service_Union.filter("cvdcu3_event_d in ('onUsageTopic/Subject')")
> .select("cvdcu3_event_attr_x").show(5,truncate=False))

```
    |cvdcu3_event_attr_x                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[{"page_id" -> "G2130854", "view" -> "FEATURES/DalmFeaturesView", "ignitionCount" -> "236", "vehicletotaluptime" -> "223568", "_description" -> "Topic/Subject user accessed"}]                                                                                                                          |
|[{"page_id" -> "G2122100", "view" -> "FEATURES/DalmFeaturesView", "ignitionCount" -> "126", "vehicletotaluptime" -> "81532", "_description" -> "Topic/Subject user accessed"}]                                                                                                                           |
|[{"page_id" -> "videos-page", "view" -> "FEATURES/DalmFeaturesView", "ignitionCount" -> "97", "vehicletotaluptime" -> "48017", "_description" -> "Topic/Subject user accessed"}]                                                                                                                               |
|[{"page_id" -> "G2157430", "view" -> "FEATURES/DalmFeaturesView", "ignitionCount" -> "126", "vehicletotaluptime" -> "81736", "_description" -> "Topic/Subject user accessed"}]  



**The column cvdcu3_event_attr_x is map column. 
|-- cvdcu3_event_attr_x: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)**
```

How can I fetch value of page_id under cvdcu3_event_attr_x column. I have tried below solutions, but it returns null:

1. (Usage_Service_Union.filter("cvdcu3_event_d in ('onUsageTopic/Subject')")
   .select("cvdcu3_event_attr_x.page_id").show(truncate=False))
2. Usage_Service_Union.registerTempTable("Usage_Service_Union")
   spark.sql("select distinct cvdcu3_event_attr_x['page_id'] from Usage_Service_Union ").show(truncate=False)
3. Usage_Service_Union.registerTempTable("Usage_Service_Union")
   spark.sql("select distinct cvdcu3_event_attr_x.page_id from Usage_Service_Union ").show(truncate=False)

In all the above case the output is below:

```
+-------+
|page_id|
+-------+
|null   |
+-------+
```

Please help!

Attaching Screenshot as well for the Solution 1 that is not working for me.[image]

Comment: solution 1 works for me

Comment: I get null values when using that solution whereas there is no null value for page_id

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. Turns out that the key name is {"page_id" that is key name includes curly brace and double quotes. The following worked for me:

```
(Usage_Service_Union.filter("cvdcu3_event_d in ('onUsageTopic/Subject')")
      .select(col("cvdcu3_event_attr_x").getItem("{\"page_id\"")).show(truncate=False))
```